# Struts2 jQuery plugin: trigger link on double click

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, hyperlink, double-click

I would like links to be trigger on double click. Something simple like this:

```
<sj:a href="%{link}" targets="target" ondblclick="javascript: return true;" onclick="javascript: return false;">Bližnjica</sj:a>
```

does not work (I guess because this is not a submit).

Maybe some JS can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery it's easier with an ID, but you can bind to any `<a>` as well:

```
$("a").bind("dblclick", function(){
  alert("Double Clicked");
}).click(function() {
  return false; //Prevent single click
});
```

However, if you want a double click, I'd suggest using an element other than `<a>` for this, like a `<span>` or `<div>`

Then it's much simpler like this:

```
$("#myDiv").bind("dblclick", function(){
  alert("Double Clicked");
  //Go to some link, etc, whatever you want
  //Example, going to a link on double-click:
  //window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

And the markup side:

```
<sj:div id="myDiv" href="%{link}">Bližnjica</sj:div>
```